Request Delays(15-20 sec every 8-10 request): Dockerized java Spring Boot Project with PostgreSQL (14)
I have a project using spring boot(2.5.5) + postgresql(14). The issue is as follows: when I make a request to an endpoint (which involves complex database queries with a large number of joins), every 8-10 requests experience a delay of 15-20 seconds. This occurs when the project and the database are running in Docker containers. However, when deployed locally without containers, there is no such issue, and requests always complete within 300-600 milliseconds. Can you suggest what might be causing the problem, with every 8-10 requests experiencing a delay of 15-20 seconds?
Optimized quieries using entity graphs and other tools. But the problem is not related with query optimization. It is about load boarders in postgresql inside docker container.

That almost feels like a connection leak in your code. Please share some code and configurations.

@M.Deinum about what leak do you think? Locally i don't have such issue. Remotely i face with this problem only when requesting complex queries

As requested please add code and configurations.

@M. Deinum -   jpa:
properties:
hibernate:
order_by:
default_null_ordering: last
format_sql: true
hbm2ddl:
auto: validate
datasource:
jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0/dev01?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
username:
password:
hikari:
maximum-pool-size: 8000;  Page findAll(Specification specification, Pageable pageable);

In specification some predicates are. That's it. Problem doesn't relate to code or config of app. Because all complex queries work in such way (every 8-10 request with complex query will be executed after 15-20 sec)

Don't add code/config etc. as comments as that is totally unreadable. 10 connections is the default size of the connection pool, if something for whatever reason holds on to that connection (a leak) requests will pile up. Hence a connection leak. 8000 connections max is also a bad idea as you don't want tha many connections too many connections will slow things down.

@M.Deinum if i i have a leak than i should get the same issue locally but i don't. So this is not about leak. The same behaviour but locally everything works fine and remotely it doesn't. (But remotely we use docker for app and db)

All the symptoms point to that and the fact that something works on x doesn't mean it works on y. Locally your DB is next to your app probably, less firewalls etc. etc. which could make things fast. Without knowing what exactly is different I'm sticking with a connection leak and I doubt the fact that it is running in a container is the only difference.

@M.Deinum you're right about such factors as firewall, server configs and others. Need to investigate and try to perfom this issue locally
